# Discord.NET c# SocketUser is returning null

Tags: c#, discord, bots, discord.net

I'm coding a c# bot and im trying to do a !user @ command which gives info about the user tagged.

This is how im getting the Id of the user

```
public async Task Info(string user)
```

This is how im transforming it into just numbers

```
user = user.Substring(3);
int k = user.Length;
user = user.Substring(0, k - 1);
```

For example: **!user <@!749020331187896410>** transforms into **749020331187896410**

And this is what im doing to get the user as i would do for Context.Message.Author

```
var client = Context.Client;
ulong id = Convert.ToUInt64(user);
var socketUser = client.GetUser(id);
```

I tried adding **as SocketUser** and **as SocketGuildUser** on the last line but still its returning null
Help :/

Comment: Is the `Server Members Intent` enabled in your bot?

Comment: Yep this did it, thank you

Comment: I'm posting that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should enable the **Server Members Intent** in the [Discord Developer Console](https://discord.com/developers):

[image: The toggle]

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
   [Command("user")]
    public async Task blizz_con(IGuildUser user)
    {
        await ReplyAsync(user.Id.ToString());
    }
```

or if you are directly working on the message:

```
message.Author.id
```